# Rails Facebook Integration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I am writing a facebook app by using ruby and rails. I will need Facebook connect and login, share, and timeline integration (posting on user's behalf). Is there any tutorial/guide or gem that you recommend.

Thank you
Cheers

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=Facebook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/) is a gem that interacts with Facebook's Graph API and can handle Facebook OAuth as well.

[Koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/) has some good examples on Github, but if you like Ryan Bates covers Koala and Facebook's Graph API in Railscasts Pro [#361](http://railscasts.com/episodes/361-facebook-graph-api) and [#363](http://railscasts.com/episodes/363-facebook-open-graph). Both are paid episodes.

[Omniauth](https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/) is a great gem for handling many different OAuth providers, including Facebook.  Ryan Bates covers it in [several episodes](http://railscasts.com/episodes?search=omniauth).

Comment: Thank you!Episode 360 was also very helpful for facebook authentication using omniauth-facebook gem

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend 3 gems for facebook authentication and login. Implementing them would be quite complex. For basic authentication you can use devise, then for facebook login, you can integrate omniauth with the omniauth-facebook gem into devise:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview